# Powershell: Pass SecureString (or PSCredential) as script parameter

Tags: powershell, parameters, arguments, parameter-passing, securestring

I have a script named `script.ps1` that starts like this:

```
Param([Parameter(Mandatory)][SecureString] $Password)

# do some stuffs
```

If I run it like this no problem:

`powershell.exe -File script.ps1`

But if I try to explicitely pass the SecureString it does not work:

`powershell.exe -File script.ps1 -Password (Read-Host -AsSecureString)`

I suspect that you can only pass classic strings as script arguments but I'm unable to find a confirmation of this anywhere.

I know you can do this and that works:

`& ./script.ps1 -Password (Read-Host -AsSecureString)`

But you are not always in a powershell session to start with.

TL/DR: should I use plain strings for passwords when using script parameters?

p.s: if `PSCredential` works better for my case that's ok too

Comment: The only data type you can submit on the command line is a _string_, there's no way you can construct a SecureString instance outside of .NET and pass it as an argument when launching powershell.exe. You'll have to refactor the parameter block to take a path to a file that contains the credentials (you can construct such a file with `Get-Credential 'dummyUserName' |Export-CliXml path\to\output.xml`)

Comment: You could also run `powershell.exe -Command "& { .\script.ps1 -Password (Read-Host -AsSecureString) }"` to have the argument be evaluated inside the inner PowerShell.

Comment: Good point, @jkiiski. A quibble (an inconsequential aside): There's no reason to use `"& { ... }"` in order to invoke code passed to PowerShell's CLI via the `-Command` (`-c`) parameter - just use `"..."` directly. Older versions of the [CLI documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) erroneously suggested that `& { ... }` is required, but this has since been corrected.

Comment: @Silex, in your use case, is the `powershell.exe` call made in a way that permits interactive prompts? If so, jkiiski's solution should work. If not, is modifying the script file an option?

Comment: Yeah both answer from jkiiski and Mathias R. Jessen work. I can also modify the script file to accept a string/xml file if needed.